# Javascript Scroll Bar Var Not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a chat system. I need the scroll bar to stay at the bottom unless the user scrolls up, and if the user scrolls up they should stay where they are unless they scroll down and get locked back into the scroll. I believe this is called, "sticky scroll."

The Javascript I have written does not save the old height. The console shows, `var oldHeight = (out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight);` as the problem when it should work fine.

I was wondering if anyone knew a better way to do this or If anyone knows why the var is not working. Thanks!

```js
function my_function() {
  var out = document.getElementById("Mess2");
  var oldHeight = (out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight);
  $('#Mess2').load("#Mess2" + ' #message_area');

  var isScrolledToBottom = (out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight >= oldHeight) && (oldHeight <= out.scrollTop);

  console.log(oldHeight, out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight, out.scrollTop);

  if (isScrolledToBottom)
    out.scrollTop = out.scrollHeight - out.clientHeight;
}

setInterval("my_function();", 1000);
```

Comment: [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788200/javascipt-scroll-bar-function-not-working)?

Comment: Dont measure the client/document/window height, but the elements scroll height.. so `elm.scrollTop(elm.scrollHeight)` would suffice to keep it at bottom

Comment: Where do you suggest placing: "elm.scrollTop(elm.scrollHeight)" in the code, everywhere I place it comes out as an error.

Comment: @MtnBros see answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, use `$("#chat").scrollTop($('#chat')[0].scrollHeight);` to scroll, the triggering of the scroll should be determined by whether the user has scrolled up, and if they scroll back to the bottom then enable scrolling again.

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  var chatElm = $("#chat");

  // turn on/off scrolling
  var autoScroll = true;
  chatElm.scroll(function() {
    autoScroll = false;

    // if height == scroll pos enable scrolling (ie, at bottom)
    if (chatElm.scrollTop() + chatElm.height() === chatElm[0].scrollHeight) {
      autoScroll = true;
    }
  });

  // scroll to bottom of div
  function scrollToBottom() {
    chatElm.scrollTop(chatElm[0].scrollHeight);
  }

  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    i++;
    chatElm.append(i + '<br>');

    // to scroll or not to scroll
    !autoScroll || scrollToBottom();
  }, 300);
})
```

```css
#chat {
  height: 100px;
  background: #ccc;
  overflow-y: auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="chat"></div>
```

Comment: While, it works in the demo, copying your code onto my website does not work, I also tried on a simpler site. I put the simple one here: livey.ml

Comment: Essentially, it works on stackoverflow, but even with a .html where it is the only code it breaks and stays at the bottom, you can't scroll up anymore.

Comment: I can't really help if don't see the code or your changes (the above works in all browsers/sites), can you put a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on https://jsbin.com or such site so can see the issue.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/domugad Should show the issue, it happens in both Firefox and Chome.

Comment: Its because the div is after the js code either move the js to bottom or wrap in an onload https://jsbin.com/narororoja/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks, the code almost works perfectly! The one problem is if someone else sends a message it does not bring you down to the new bottom if you where at the old bottom, My code is: https://jsbin.com/tayonic , It should reload the div which finds the new message, except the cursor if it is at the bottom is supposed to move to the new bottom but does not. Do you know why?

Comment: np, dont forget to upvote and accept. I looked at your jsbin, im not sure what your expecting from me lol, its gone alittle beyond the scope of SO, i.e question is answered. Anyways, if a new message comes in, then just toggle autoScroll. `$('#Mess2').load("#Mess2" + ' #message_area');` is not a good idea. what you should be doing is either polling the server for new messages (ajax, server-sent-events) or better web sockets, so the dom is built from received json, also using jquery `load` your lose all the event handlers on the inject dom. good luck

Comment: also having a 1 millisecond timeout, wont give the user enough time to scroll to the bottom, and it never sticks/enables, also its hammering your network/server etc

Comment: I made a iccle chat script a while back, you might be intrested in, one using SSE https://github.com/lcherone/sse-chat-example and one using electron and p2p https://github.com/lcherone/p2p-chat for giggles